# telegram api send message to specific user

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I create a bot, add that bot to my group and now I can send messages to group via api:
[https://api.telegram.org/bot'](https://api.telegram.org/bot%27) + token + '/sendMessage' + '?chat_id=' + chat_id + '&text=' + text

And that message is visible to everyone in a group.
How can I send a message in a group that is visible only to a specific user (I have a user id)?

Comment: I don't think Telegram supports such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send a user specific message in a group. Still you have other options:

- Send a link to the group and mention the user to start your bot with that link for their message
- Send a message with inline button that would only work for that specific user. Then when the user clicks on that button, a callback alert appears with the message.

Comment: how do you mention a user using the api? I can't find it on the sendmessage documentation.